# "for" attribute not working inside button for Firefox

Tags: html, css

I want to customize the input element by changing the text to "Choose file ..." and hide the file's name. Also if a user click the button a window is opened for user to choose file. The code is

```
<button>
 <label for="upload"> Choose file ... </label>
</button>
<input type="file" id="upload" style="display:none">
```

With Chrome, if I click the button a window is  popped up for me to choose the file. However it doesn't work with Firefox and IE. Do you know how can I make it work for all three browsers? Thank you.

Comment: Try [*validating your code*](https://validator.w3.org) (and this has nothing to do with javascript).

Comment: Try putting the button inside the label, instead of the label inside the button.

Comment: @Barmar — That's invalid HTML. If a label has a form control (like a button) as a descendant, then any for attribute **must** match the ID of that form control. You can't label two form elements with one label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `label` tag does not work for buttons.  It is by and large used with radio buttons.  The below should do what you are looking for:

```html
<button id="btnFile" onclick="upload.click();">
  Choose file ...
</button>
<input type="file" id="upload" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. A label cannot be a descendant of a button.

Remove the button:

```
<label for="upload"> Choose file ... </label>
<input type="file" id="upload" style="display:none">
```

(Tested in Firefox. I don't have a copy of IE to hand.)

If you want something that *looks* like a button, then style it that way with CSS.