# How to implement context menus similarly to youtube cards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm on my way to learn a bit of CSS and today I've found myself wanting to implement a similar context menu (the one it's shown when you the vertical elipsis on youtube cards is clicked) but my attempt didn't make it very far :D . Here's what I've got:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-opener {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle,
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    style-type: none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:checked+ul {
    display: block;
}

.style-scope .menu-renderer {
    --layout-inline_-_display: inline-flex;
    --icon-button-icon-height: 24px;
    --icon-button-icon-width: 24px;
    --spec-icon-active-other: #606060;
    --spec-icon-inactive: #909090;
    --spec-text-disabled: #909090;
    --spec-text-secondary: #606060;
    align-items: var(--layout-center-center_-_align-items);
    color: var(--menu-renderer-button-color, var(--spec-icon-inactive));
    cursor: pointer;
    display: var(--layout-inline_-_display);
    fill: var(--iron-icon-fill-color, currentcolor);
    width: var(--icon-button-icon-width, 100%);
    background: transparent;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener1">...</label>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener1" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Foo1</li>
            <li>Bar1</li>
            <li>Baz1</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener1">...</label>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener1" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Foo2</li>
            <li>Bar2</li>
            <li>Baz2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <icon-button id="button" class="dropdown-opener dropdown-trigger style-scope menu-renderer">
            <button id="button" class="style-scope icon-button" aria-label="Action menu">
                <icon class="style-scope menu-renderer">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <g class="style-scope icon">
                            <path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z" class="style-scope icon"></path>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </icon>
            </button>
        </icon-button>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener2" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Foo3</li>
            <li>Bar3</li>
            <li>Baz3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the code is dirty and broken... but there are major problems with my attempts I didn't know how to fix:

1. Misplaced context menus when clicked the elipsis button
2. Items showing the bulletpoint mark
3. Items style is ugly in comparison to youtube's one which is really clean

So if you could explain how to address those ones in order to make something usable out of my attempt that'd be awesome.

Or if my approach is all wrong, unusable and ready to throw to the bin... could you please explain what'd the best to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Issue #1

*Misplaced context menus when clicking the overflow menu button*. The context menus are not actually misplaced. The **`for`** attribute in your **`<label>`** element refers to the wrong context menus. For example, the `for` value of your `<label>` element in the first `.container` has a value of `menu-opener1`, but the `for` value on the `<label>` element in the **second** `.container` has the exact same value. Clicking either label causes the dropdown menu in the first container to be opened because both labels cause the hidden checkbox on the first container to be checked.

What can we do? Simply change the `id` value so that each dropdown menu has a unique id value. Then, use that id value for the `for` value inside your `<label>` element.

---

### Issue #2

To hide the bulletins of `li` elements inside a `ul`, you have to use **`list-style-type: none`** on your CSS and **not** `style-type: none`.

---

### Issue #3

This is a very subjective matter. A design can look clean to one but look unclean to others. Nevertheless, I tried to achieve what I wanted to see. Here are some things that you can change to improve the design aspect.

- Change your font-family so that it suits your theme. I chose a sans-serif font family here.
- Add a background to your context menu. Here, I chose the color white.
- Add space between each `li` element. Here, I used `line-height`. You can also use `padding` or `margin` on each `li` element.
- Add a `box-shadow` to show elevation. [Google's Material Design recommends using this technique to show that an element's z-position is higher.](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html)
- Allow transition from when the context menu changes from visible to invisible and vice-versa. This means avoiding using un-transition-able CSS properties (e.g. `visibility` and `display`). Here, I chose to use `transform: scale` and `opacity` transition.

---

### Other concerns

Semantically, your HTML tags are incorrect.

- The `<nav>` (navigation) element is used to navigate between pages. Here, you should probably use [`<menu>` element instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu). However, as it is still experimental, I chose to use `<section>`.
- You are using some nonexistant HTML tags (e.g. `<icon-button>` and `<icon>`). Try consulting [here for valid HTML tags](https://html.com/tags/) and [here for valid SVG tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element).
- The last `.container` item has a button that will check the hidden checkbox. However, [the `<button>` element does not work with `<label>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048990/9060223). So, try to make the `<label>` element visually look like a button instead. You can use `:active` and `:hover` CSS pseudoselectors to change the button style when it is pressed and hovered respectively. Furthermore, this reduces nesting.
- Try to always avoid using inline styles when styling using CSS is possible (e.g. your inline SVG styles)
- *Personal preference.* Most frameworks use `.container` to contain the whole page, so I have opted to use the class name `.box` instead of `.container`.

---

Here's the runnable snippet.

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 8px;
}

.dropdown-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/Qt3Qwgp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition:
    transform 0.25s ease,
    opacity 0.25s ease;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  right: 10px;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:checked + ul {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown-opener-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  right: 8px;
  top: 0;
}

.icon-button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 
    box-shadow .25s ease,
    background .25s ease,
    transform .25s ease;
  background: #ffffffdd;
}

.icon-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

.icon-button:active {
  background: #ffffff77;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.icon-button ~ .dropdown-menu {
  top: 1.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <section class="dropdown layer--topright">
    <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener1"></label>
    <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener1" type="checkbox">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Foo1</li>
      <li>Bar1</li>
      <li>Baz1</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <section class="dropdown layer--topright">
    <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener2"></label>
    <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener2" type="checkbox">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Foo2</li>
      <li>Bar2</li>
      <li>Baz2</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <section class="dropdown layer--topright">
    <label class="dropdown-opener-button icon-button" for="menu-opener3">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope icon">
        <g class="style-scope icon">
          <path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z" class="style-scope icon"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </label>
    <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener3" type="checkbox">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Foo3</li>
      <li>Bar3</li>
      <li>Baz3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

---

### Update

Not having a crystal-clear understanding of what the OP meant by *how hard would it be to make the menu items change the state when hovering with the mouse*, I decided to create an effect on hovered and a different effect (ripple) on click for the `<li>` elements. I recommend reading this [writing on creating a ripple effect](https://medium.com/@leonardo.monteiro.fernandes/css-techniques-for-material-ripple-effect-3f0ece3062a0).

Also, as per request, the functionality to hide the menus when a click outside of the menu's box has been added. Here's the runnable snippet.

```js
// Closing menu on outside click
const outsideClickListener = event => {
  let checkedToggle = document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle:checked')
  let openedMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle:checked + .dropdown-menu')
  
  // If click is performed on checkbox (through label), do nothing
  if (event.target.classList.contains('dropdown-toggle')) {
    return
  }
  
  // If click is performed on label, uncheck all other dropdown-toggle
  if (event.target.classList.contains('dropdown-opener') ||
      event.target.classList.contains('dropdown-opener-button')) {
    let forId = event.target.getAttribute('for')
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle').forEach(toggle => {
      if (forId !== toggle.getAttribute('id'))
        toggle.checked = false
    })
    return
  }
  
  // If click is performed outside opened menu
  if (openedMenu && !openedMenu.contains(event.target)) {
    checkedToggle.checked = false
  }
}
document.addEventListener('click', outsideClickListener)

// Ripple effect on li elements
const createRipple = event => {
  let li = event.target
  let liBox = li.getBoundingClientRect()
  let x = event.pageX - liBox.left
  let y = event.pageY - liBox.top
  let animDuration = 350
  let animationStart, animationFrame
  
  let animationStep = timestamp => {
    if (!animationStart) animationStart = timestamp
    let frame = timestamp - animationStart
    if (frame < animDuration) {
      let easing = (frame / animDuration) * (2 - (frame / animDuration))
      let circle = `circle at ${x}px ${y}px`
      let color = `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${0.2 * (1 - easing)})`
      let stop = `${100 * easing}%`
      li.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(${circle}, ${color} ${stop}, transparent ${stop})`
      animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(animationStep)
    }
    else {
      li.style.backgroundImage = ''
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationStep)
    }
  }
  
  animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(animationStep)
}
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li')
listItems.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('click', createRipple)
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 8px;
}

.dropdown-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/Qt3Qwgp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition:
    transform 0.25s ease,
    opacity 0.25s ease;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  right: 10px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  padding: 7.5px 0 7.5px 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:checked + ul {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 7.5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background: #00000012;
}

.dropdown-opener-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  right: 8px;
  top: 0;
}

.dropdown-opener-button svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.icon-button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 
    box-shadow .25s ease,
    background .25s ease,
    transform .25s ease;
  background: #ffffffdd;
}

.icon-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

.icon-button:active {
  background: #ffffffaa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.icon-button ~ .dropdown-menu {
  top: 1.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <section class="dropdown layer--topright">
    <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener1"></label>
    <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener1" type="checkbox">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Foo1</li>
      <li>Bar1</li>
      <li>Baz1</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <section class="dropdown layer--topright">
    <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener2"></label>
    <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener2" type="checkbox">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Foo2</li>
      <li>Bar2</li>
      <li>Baz2</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  <section class="dropdown layer--topright">
    <label class="dropdown-opener-button icon-button" for="menu-opener3">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope icon">
        <g class="style-scope icon">
          <path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z" class="style-scope icon"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </label>
    <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener3" type="checkbox">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Foo3</li>
      <li>Bar3</li>
      <li>Baz3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is the best answer so far and really cool... how hard would it be to make the menu items change the state when hovering with the mouse? And finally, how hard would it be to close the menu when clicking outside the menu (like youtube)? Other than that, it already deserves my upvote

Comment: @BPL I'm not sure what you meant by changing menu items' states. You can change its *style*, though, using the `:hover` pseudo-selector (this is demonstrated on the third box). By clicking outside the menu, do you mean clicking inside the box or outside the box? Either way, you'd need JS for that. There are many answers in SO dealing with your second question.

Comment: What do you mean is demonstrated on the [third box](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wweicinbb1sdfks/2020-06-17_17-13-59.mp4), i don't see anything changing when hovering the item on the 3rd box (similarly to youtube)... Anyway, about the style change when hovering that's something easy i'd know how to do by myself, forget about it... on the other hand, about the menu dissapearing and js... would it be too difficult to implement (like youtube's)? Anyway, this is just an extra and your question is more than good enough already as it is so tyvm.

Comment: @BPL Oh I see. You meant changing the style of the `<li>` elements on hover? You can use the `:hover` pseudo-selector too to change the style in CSS too. As for the Youtube design, I can't seem to find the overflow menu in my PC. In my mobile phone, it is simply impossible to hover on the `<li>` element. Therefore, I am not sure what kind of effect you want. I wanted to leave a note mentioning that when it comes to a question of design, adding a screenshot of the design that you want to implement in HTML + CSS may help clear up any confusion.

Comment: It is a really nice and accurate attempt, that you earned a "thanks for this answer" from me :p

Comment: @BPL I have updated my answer to include ripple effect and the additional functionality to close menus on clicking outside.

Comment: I don't know why people didn't upvote much more to the good answer provided by `Girish Sasidharan` but the community has speaken and decided... For me both this and @Girish's answer have been equally good and solved the thread perfectly but i can't share the validation/bounty, can't I? As explained in Girish I left the community decide here as i didn't know how to choose.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-opener').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').children('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show')
  });
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!(e.target.matches('.dropdown-opener') || e.target.matches('.fa.fa-ellipsis-v'))) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');      
     //debugger;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle,
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:checked+ul {
  display: block;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #efefef;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 60px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px -1px rgba(196, 186, 196, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px -1px rgba(196, 186, 196, 1);
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px -1px rgba(196, 186, 196, 1);
}

ul.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #030303;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.style-scope .menu-renderer {
  --layout-inline_-_display: inline-flex;
  --icon-button-icon-height: 24px;
  --icon-button-icon-width: 24px;
  --spec-icon-active-other: #606060;
  --spec-icon-inactive: #909090;
  --spec-text-disabled: #909090;
  --spec-text-secondary: #606060;
  align-items: var(--layout-center-center_-_align-items);
  color: var(--menu-renderer-button-color, var(--spec-icon-inactive));
  cursor: pointer;
  display: var(--layout-inline_-_display);
  fill: var(--iron-icon-fill-color, currentcolor);
  width: var(--icon-button-icon-width, 100%);
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener2"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Wishlist</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Share</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Not interested</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener2"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Wishlist</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Share</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Not interested</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hi Please check this fiddle, Hope this will help you

https://jsfiddle.net/hm2zuo3r/2/

Comment: Hi, thanks, yeah, similarly to @anatolhiman fiddle this one is definitely solving many of the issues I've mentioned in my question but it's still lacking important things. For instance, when you hover the items they won't change the state and when you click outside the menu this won't become invisible. Said otherwise, it won't behave as a context menu like youtube's

Comment: @BPL I have updated the fiddle url, please check it.

Comment: Wow, this one is very cool. Right now your answer is the best one so far and worthy to be validated/bountied... it's completely usable as it is and other than some minor details like not overlapping the menu with the menu button seems perfect. I'll leave the community to decide which answer is the best one, at the end of the week the answer which has received more upvotes will be validated/bountied... Why? Because at this point it's become difficult for me to decide as i see a lot of good answers here :/ , thank you very much! Here's my upvote in the meantime ;)

Comment: It is a really nice and accurate attempt, that even you earned a "thanks for this answer" from me :p

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use unique IDs (unique naming) in order to trigger the correct menu. Now you trigger the first menu in the code while clicking any of the triggers.
2. Use list-style-type: none in CSS in order to remove bullets from list
3. You need to style your ul.dropdown-menu item in CSS with some padding, a background-color (white for example) and ul.dropdown-menu li with font-size, line-height etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-opener {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle,
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    style-type: none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:checked+ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: orange;

}

.style-scope .menu-renderer {
    --layout-inline_-_display: inline-flex;
    --icon-button-icon-height: 24px;
    --icon-button-icon-width: 24px;
    --spec-icon-active-other: #606060;
    --spec-icon-inactive: #909090;
    --spec-text-disabled: #909090;
    --spec-text-secondary: #606060;
    align-items: var(--layout-center-center_-_align-items);
    color: var(--menu-renderer-button-color, var(--spec-icon-inactive));
    cursor: pointer;
    display: var(--layout-inline_-_display);
    fill: var(--iron-icon-fill-color, currentcolor);
    width: var(--icon-button-icon-width, 100%);
    background: transparent;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener1">...</label>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener1" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Foo1</a></li>
            <li>Bar1</li>
            <li>Baz1</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <label class="dropdown-opener" for="menu-opener2">...</label>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener2" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Foo2</li>
            <li>Bar2</li>
            <li>Baz2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="sample" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <nav class="dropdown layer--topright">
        <icon-button id="button" class="dropdown-opener dropdown-trigger style-scope menu-renderer">
            <button id="button" class="style-scope icon-button" aria-label="Action menu">
                <icon class="style-scope menu-renderer">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <g class="style-scope icon">
                            <path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z" class="style-scope icon"></path>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </icon>
            </button>
        </icon-button>
        <input class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu-opener2" type="checkbox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Foo3</li>
            <li>Bar3</li>
            <li>Baz3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've edited my question with new code. I've tried to apply your points 1. & 2. but unfortunately for some reason I'm still doing it wrong... Could you please post how the snippet should look like in your answer?

Comment: The two first menu IDs are still identical, they are both called menu-opener1. The last menu code block is different and does not seem to work at all, if you make it the same as the two first ones, but with menu-opener3 as its ID it should work. You have not tried to style the menu (ul etc.) with CSS, if you try that I can guide you once I see your attempt. To start styling the menu itself, start by creating a css rule for `.dropdown-menu {  }`.

Comment: Added in correct IDs for the two first menus + some CSS to get you started. Do you see the pattern to work with here? For the third menu I don't know what you want to achieve, so I did not touch it.